# How does teamviewer resolve control conflicts?

Tags: windows, teamviewer

I want to be able to log in to my grandpa's computer to fix some stuff for him while he's sitting there via teamviewer. Out of curiosity, what would happen if he tried to move the mouse or supply keyboard input while I was doing the same? Which interface would get priority and why?

Answer (score 4):

In short: it doesn't.

You both will fight for control. Its like if you have 2 keyboards and try to type at the same time... both entries will get accepted by the computer and you get both entries.

Also for mouse - you both will fight for 1 mouse. You can "lock out" the local keyboard and mouse.. but thats it. None will get priority.